# jQuery pass element to dataTransfer property

Tags: jquery, events, object, drag-and-drop, data-transfer

Trying to pass a jQuery object to the `dataTransfer` property during a drag/drop sequence. After adding the property to `jQuert.event.props` array I'm able to assign it, but it returns undefined on during the `drop` event. Not sure what I'm missing here- seems really straightforward.

Javascript:

```
function dragClip(clip, event){

    event.dataTransfer.el = clip;

    /* Console confirms event.dataTransfer.el is the jQuery object */
}

function dropClip(target, event){

    target.append(event.dataTransfer.el);

    /* event.dataTransfer.el no longer has the object... where'd it go?? */
}

jQuery.event.props.push('dataTransfer');

$('#titles')
    .bind('dragenter dragover', false)
    .bind('drop', function(event){

        dropClip($(this), event);
    });

$('.clip').bind('dragstart', function(event){

    dragClip($(this), event);
});
```

---

UPDATE:

Rewritten to remove the verbosity. Had included other stuff in there, but an anonymous function will do just fine:

```
jQuery.event.props.push('dataTransfer');

$('#titles')
    .bind('dragenter dragover', false)
    .bind('drop', function(event){

        $(this).append(event.dataTransfer.el);
    });

$('.clip').bind('dragstart', function(event){

    event.dataTransfer.el = $(this);
});
```

---

UPDATE

As per @barney's final answer, my final working code. I noticed that using the original event didn't allow me to pass an object as data, so instead I applied the ID and rebuilt the jQuery object on drop. Also tightened everything up by getting rid of the declared functions. Less code, same result.

```
$('#titles')
    .bind('dragenter dragover', false)
    .bind('drop', function(event){

        $(this).append($('#' + event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('clip')));
    });

$('.clip')
    .bind('dragstart', function(event){

        event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('clip', $(this).attr('id'));
    });
```

Comment: +1 for this "UPDATE" part.This helped me.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Personally, I try to play with jQuery internals as little as possible and extract the original event object where possible. When using drag and drop in the past, I've always made use of `event.originalEvent.dataTransfer`.

Comment: yeah, I considered something like this. It's just so weird- I should be able to attach the jquery object to the dataTransfer property. I can do it in vanilla JS, not sure why it would work differently in jQuery if dataTransfer's added to the event property array

Comment: Personally, I try to play with jQuery internals as little as possible. When using drag and drop in the past, I've always made use of `event.originalEvent.dataTransfer`.

Comment: Funnily enough, using that instead of adding dataTransfer to jQuery works. I've accepted your answer and appreciate the help. Would doubly appreciate if you could append your answer with your suggestion on event.originalEvent for others' reference